# Convert any input timestamp ex (4/25/2021 20.01.42) to Correct Postgres TimeStamp (YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS)

Tags: postgresql

I always get random timestamp format input for a data/time field from a file. Irrespective of the input, i always want it get converted into correct Postgres timestamp format.

ex1: (4/25/2021 20.01.42) to Correct Postgres TimeStamp (YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS)

ex2: sometime the format we receive from file is (10/05/2022 09:17:23)

I'm getting error as

> invalid date format or convert 24 hr clock to 12 hr for example-1 etc.

Can we write a generic conversion statement in Postgres?

Comment: You can't convert "any" input. Is `10/05` 5th October or 10th May?

Answer (score 1):

24h:

```
  select to_timestamp('4/25/2021 20.01.42','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS');
```

12h:

```
select to_char( to_timestamp ('4/25/2021 20.01.42','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'HH12:MI:SS PM' )
```

Further info:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datetime-appendix.html